# python dataframe can sort and add like this

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'll just show what I want

cuz my english is not enough for explain this

sorry for my rudeness

I have this

```
    col1 col2 col3
0   A    2    0
1   A    1    1
2   B    9    9
3   C    4    3
```

and I want this

```
    col1 col2 col3
0   A    3    1
1   B    9    9
2   C    4    3
```

could anyone have idea for this?

thx for reading and sorry for spoil the board

Comment: Use `df = df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).sum()`, it is dupe :(